# Simple JavaScript ES6 vs require() importing

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, browserify, babeljs, javascript-import

I'm getting ready to use ES6 module import/export via babel but came across this confusing statement in this [article](https://www.sitepoint.com/setting-up-es6-project-using-babel-browserify/).

It states:

> The power of ES6’s `import` and `export` combined with the `require()` method, gives us the freedom to organize all of the client-side code into modules and at the same time write the code using all the power of the new version of JavaScript.

This makes it sound like ES6's system and `require()` serve two different purposes, thereby making this `babel/browserify` approach the best one to take. My understanding was that they both do the same things, just a little differently. Could anyone help explain this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This statement is contradictory. If you got into ES6/ES7 you won't want to use *CommonJS*-style `require`, but you'll always want to load modules asynchronously using `import`.

In fact, ES6/ES7 have a programmatic way of importing modules: `System.import(...)`, but the [loader specification](https://whatwg.github.io/loader/) is still being discussed...

Until it gets recommendation status, there's a polyfill (and more than this...): [*SystemJS*](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs).

I would avoid any other module loading syntax from now, because your code will be perfectly executable in standard Web browsers in some years with few modifications.

#### OP asked in some comment...

> Why will System.import(...) from ES6 be needed for js modules when we
>   have the ES6 import/export module loading capabilities? Aren't they
>   performing the same tasks?

`import` statement can be only at the **top** of a code file. Sometimes you know what files to load based on executing some kind of logic, and `import` syntax doesn't support conditionals.

For example, let's say you've an application which requires *plugins*, and some options have a flag called `loadPlugins` which can be `true` or `false`. Thus, you'll want to load them if the application wants them loaded:

```
if(options.loadPlugins) {
   Promise.all(
      options.plugins.map(plugin => System.import(plugin.path))
   ).then(() => {
      // Do stuff when all plugins have been already loaded!
   });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Why will `System.import(...)` from ES6 be needed for js modules when we have the ES6 `import/export` module loading capabilities? Aren't they performing the same tasks?

Comment: @qarthandso I'm going to answer this in my own answer as an update ;)

Comment: Ah I understand. Thank you. Are you using that code from a specific plugin? Or is `Promise` a js keyword? I don't understand the code but I understand the concept of `import` vs `System.import` now!

Comment: @qarthandso Oops! `Promise` is already available in modern browsers. It's the implementation of this standard: https://promisesaplus.com/. It's an elegant way to implement asynchronous programming. `System.import` returns a promise, and you can attach a `then` handler to do something once the operation has been completed.

Comment: @qarthandso Since you'll get many promises because you would call a `System.import` per plugin path, you need `Promise.all`, which takes an array of promises as argument, and creates a new promise that groups all in a single one. That is, I can do something once all grouped promises gets the completed state!

Comment: @qarthandso Check this URL https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Thank you very much. Will start researching!

Comment: @qarthandso You're welcome! Now you've reasons to use your spare time